# How can I make a unique constraint on multiple column in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create table tImprumuturi
(
     ID_Imprumut int identity primary key,
     DataImprumut date default getdate(),
     DataScadenta as (dateadd(day,2,DataImprumut)) persisted,
     CodCD char(10) foreign key references tCD(CodCd)not null,
     CodCV char(10) foreign key references tCaseteVideo(CodCaseta),
     CodAb char(10) foreign key references tAbonati(CodAbonat) not null,
     CONSTRAINT ucCodes UNIQUE (CodCD,CodCV,CodAb)
)
```

I don't want to have many of the same CodCD OR CodCV OR CodAb but never two records with the same CodCD AND CodCV AND CodAb. My code is at the top as you can see, and even if I have the instruction `CONSTRAINT ucCodes UNIQUE (CodCD,CodCV,CodAb)`, it still let me to insert two or more records with the same CodCD AND CodCV AND CodAb. Below you can see my records

```
insert into tImprumuturi(CodCV,CodCD,CodAb)
values('CV21','CD20','ab9')
insert into tImprumuturi(CodCV,CodCD,CodAb)
values('CV21','CD19','ab9')
```

Comment: 1) Please don't use that `t` prefix for table names. 2) If you have SQL2008+ then you could use `DATE` data type for `DataImprumut` column. 3) You don't have to create a scalar function to define a computed column (SQL2005+). Instead, you could use `DataScadenta AS (DATEADD(DAY,2,DataImprumut)) [PERSISTED]` (PERSISTED is optional). Using a scalar function (`DataScadenta AS scalar function`) has some performance penalties.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table  tImprumuturi add unique index(CodCD, CodCV, CodAb);
```

Comment: Bogdan Sahlean, your information was so helpful that it comes me to say "I love you!".I've changed data type for DataImprumut and DataScadenta as you say and it works! Thank you! Kevin Bowersox, I can say thank you for your answer. It is not working, maby becouse I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and it has different sintaxes to work.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to add a unique constraint is to explicitly create a unique index:

```
create unique index tImprumuturi_CodCD_CodCV_CodAb on tImprumuturi(CodCD, CodCV, CodAb);
```

You can also do it in the `create table` statement directly:

```
create table . . .
    constraint unique(CodCD, CodCV, CodAb)
    . . .
```

These are both equivalent to the `alter table` statement in functionality.  I happen to prefer the explicit index creation.

EDIT:

Your question still is not clear about what you want to be unique.  If you want the individual values not to be repeated, then create a separate unique index on each one:

```
create unique index tImprumuturi_CodCD_CodCV_CodAb on tImprumuturi(CodCD);
create unique index tImprumuturi_CodCD_CodCV_CodAb on tImprumuturi(CodCV);
create unique index tImprumuturi_CodCD_CodCV_CodAb on tImprumuturi(CodAb);
```

Comment: Kevin Bowersox and Gordon Linoff, I can say thank you for your answer. It is not working, maby becouse I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and it has different sintaxes to work. I've tryed:                                                                     alter table tImprumuturi
  add constraint ucCodes UNIQUE clustered (CodCD,CodCV,CodAB)... alter table tImprumuturi
  add constraint ucCodes UNIQUE nonclustered (CodCD,CodCV,CodAB) but  it stil allow me to insert same values for more different registration.

Comment: insert into tImprumuturi(CodCV,CodCD,DataImprumut,CodAb)
values('CV21','CD19','2013/05/15','ab9')
insert into tImprumuturi(CodCV,CodCD,CodAb)
values('CV21','CD20','ab9') As you can see, for ab9 I have CV21 value both the first record, and in the second.

Comment: @Razvan . . . Then your question is unclear and you should edit it to clarify what you mean.  I would suggest you describe exactly what values you don't want to allow.

Comment: **I don't want to have many of the same CodCD OR CodCV OR CodAb but never two records with the same CodCD AND CodCV AND CodAb. My code is at the top as you can see, and even if I have the instruction "CONSTRAINT ucCodes UNIQUE (CodCD,CodCV,CodAb)", it still let me to insert two or more records with the same CodCD AND CodCV AND CodAb. Below you can see my records**

Comment: insert into tImprumuturi(CodCV,CodCD,CodAb)
values('CV21','CD20','ab9')
insert into tImprumuturi(CodCV,CodCD,CodAb)
values('CV21','CD19','ab9')